# How to delete a temp folder in Google Cloud (TPU) VM?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tpu

So I'm following the mesh-transformer fine-tuning [repo](https://github.com/kingoflolz/mesh-transformer-jax) to fine-tune GPT-J. I've fine-tuned a model on a Google Cloud PTU-VM before, but then deleted the fine-tuned model. Now, I'm trying to fine-tune a new model in the same VM, but the code is trying to open a tpu_logs file. It says it doesn't have permission, but I'm thinking maybe it's because it's deleted, not sure. Anyways, has anyone encountered this problem before?

I get a ton of these pop up in the terminal: `Could not open the log file '/tmp/tpu_logs/tpu_driver.[vm-code].[my-account].log.INFO.20220623-164754.59430': Permission denied`

It's as if there's something in the codebase that is aware that I've used the model for fine-tuning before and it's trying to (maybe?) continue where it left off?

Any thoughts on how to resolve this issue?

The entire output looks like:

```
.
.
.
Could not open the log file '/tmp/tpu_logs/tpu_driver.[vm-code].[my-account].log.INFO.20220623-164754.59430': Permission denied
Could not open any log file.
jax devices: 8
jax runtime initialized in 3.53237s
`--tune_model_path` passed: we are beginning a fine-tuning run
path to load checkpoint from: gs://[my-bucket]/step_383500/
setting up datasets
initializing network
/home/[my-username]/miniconda3/envs/finetune-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/experimental/maps.py:527: UserWarning: xmap is an experimental feature and probably has bugs!
  warn("xmap is an experimental feature and probably has bugs!")
/home/[my-username]/miniconda3/envs/finetune-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/lib/xla_bridge.py:429: UserWarning: jax.host_count has been renamed to jax.process_count. This alias will eventually be removed; please update your code.
  warnings.warn(
Could not open the log file '/tmp/tpu_logs/tpu_driver.[vm-code].[my-account].log.INFO.20220623-164754.59430': Permission denied
.
.
.
Could not open any log file.
Could not open the log file '/tmp/tpu_logs/tpu_driver.[vm-code].[my-account].log.INFO.20220623-164754.59430': Permission denied
Could not open any log file.
/home/[my-username]/miniconda3/envs/finetune-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/lib/xla_bridge.py:416: UserWarning: jax.host_id has been renamed to jax.process_index. This alias will eventually be removed; please update your code.
  warnings.warn(
key shape (8, 2)
in shape (1, 2048)
dp 1
mp 8
Could not open the log file '/tmp/tpu_logs/tpu_driver.[vm-code].[my-account].log.INFO.20220623-164754.59430': Permission denied
Could not open any log file.
.
.
.
Could not open any log file.
Could not open the log file '/tmp/tpu_logs/tpu_driver.[vm-code].[my-account].log.INFO.20220623-164754.59430': Permission deniedd
Could not open any log file.
Total parameters: 6053381344
loading network
Could not open the log file '/tmp/tpu_logs/tpu_driver.[vm-code].[my-account].log.INFO.20220623-164754.59430': Permission denied
Could not open any log file.
Could not open the log file '/tmp/tpu_logs/tpu_driver.[vm-code].[my-account].log.INFO.20220623-164754.59430': Permission denied
.
.
.
```

EDIT: The log file permission error seems to pop up when I try to run `import tensorflow as tf`.

Answer (score 1):

From the results of the console that you are sharing, this might be happening since the account you are using currently doesn’t have the proper permissions (Storage Legacy > Storage Legacy Bucket Writer and Storage Legacy > Storage Legacy Bucket Reader).

Also I can see that you are using JAX with your Cloud TPU, to have a better control of the memory usage with JAX, you can refer to this [troubleshooting guide.](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/device_memory_profiling.html)

Additionally, here’s some [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-disk-full-resize#full) that could help you when your disks are full, either they can be resized or you could delete some files in it.

Comment: I think it might be because I used one computer to upload data and another one to upload the model? I was able to go into the tmp/tpu_logs folder and it had logs with the ssh from one machine while I was using my other machine. I tried to switch machines, but I think I will need to redo the VM and make sure I use the same machine.

Comment: Thank you for the information about how you created the VM, and yes, you might need to re-create the VM and assign it on the proper machine that you are using.